# AmazonCloudWatchClient not sending HTTP requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

first time i'm using aws api in java to get the cloud watch statistics for my ec2-instance. i googled about this and i found some code snippet. here it is

```
AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatch = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey));
        cloudWatch.setEndpoint("ec2-<my-static-ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com");
        long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        Dimension instanceDimension = new Dimension();
        instanceDimension.setName("Instanceid");
        instanceDimension.setValue(InstanceId);
        GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
                .withStartTime(
                        new Date(new Date().getTime()
                                - offsetInMilliseconds))
                .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
                .withPeriod(60 * 60)
                .withDimensions(
                        new Dimension().withName("InstanceId").withValue(
                                InstanceId))
                .withMetricName("CPUUtilization")
                .withStatistics("Average", "Maximum")
                .withEndTime(new Date());

        GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatch
                .getMetricStatistics(request);
        double avgCPUUtilization = 0;
        List dataPoint = getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints();
        for (Object aDataPoint : dataPoint) {
            Datapoint dp = (Datapoint) aDataPoint;
            avgCPUUtilization = dp.getAverage();
            System.out.println(InstanceId
                    + " instance's average CPU utilization : "
                    + dp.getAverage());
        }
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        System.out
                .println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means the request was made  "
                        + "to Amazon EC2, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
        System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());

    }
```

so, using this code i tried to get statistics, but first time it throws error saying

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:Connection to https://ec2-<my-static-ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com refused
```

then i thought it was sending https requests. so i enabled ssl on my instance and tried, then i'm getting below exception.

```
 com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: peer not authenticated
```

i was using OpenJDK in my instance, so i thought that may causing the problem. then i removed openjdk and installed Oracle JDK 1.7. but still same problem.

My questions are,

1) how can i send only HTTP (instead of HTTPS) requests to get statistics?

2)how to get rid of this problem, so that i can get my results?

But please don't ask me to read any docs, because i messed up by searching in net, blogs,forums, docs... etc. then i end up here. so, please just provide me solution or tell me where i'm going wrong.

Can anybody please help me out this issue.

thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution.

1) removed setting end point for AmazonCloudWatchClient.

2) problem with the AWS credentials (Access key ID, Secret key).So, i created another set of credentials and gave CloudWatchFullAccess policy for the user.

Now it is working like Charm... :-)

Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same issue..you said you removed setting endpoint..so how do we pass endpoint?